# Why can I not pass this function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to pass `document.getElementById` as an argument:

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="el"></div>
```

And this javascript:

```
var test = function(fn) {
  alert(fn("el"));
}
// This works
test(function(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
});
// This fails
test(document.getElementById);
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/joshcomley/tv7chn9q/

I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome, for example.

Why is this so?

Comment: because javascript :-)

Comment: Because you are passing the function devoid of any context. You could bind it with `document.getElementById.bind(document)`.

Comment: because "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this example.

```js
var item = "This is a global variable";

var thing = {
  item: "a value",
  findInThing: function(prop) {
    return this[prop];
  }
}

alert(thing.findInThing("item"));

function call(a_func) {
    return a_func("item"); 
}

alert(call(thing.findInThing));
```

The value of `this` inside a function depends on the context in which is is called.

You are calling `getElementById` after detaching it from the context of `document`.

It isn't being involved with a DOM document to find the element in, so it fails.

You can create a new function which wraps around another one and then calls it in a specific context using bind:

```
var myGEBI = document.getElementById.bind(document);
test(myGEBI);
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById need to be executed with document as context you can fix that using bind:

```
test(document.getElementById.bind(document));
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/tv7chn9q/1/)